# How to access child components properties and methods in single variable?

Tags: angular, viewchild, data-sharing

I have one parent component and multiple child components.

```
<parent>
  <child1></child1>
  <child2></child2>
  ...
</parent>
```

In order to communicate between parent child either I can make use of event decorators `(@Input/@Output)`. Alternately I can make use of multiple `@ViewChild` like below to access child properties and methods. (Not considering services and Observables)

```
@ViewChild('child1') child1: Child1;
@ViewChild('child2') child2: Child2; 
//.... so on
```

I dont want to use event decorators as well as multiple @ViewChild to store the reference of each child components.

Is there any way in angular similar to @ViewChild where I can get the reference of all the child's in one variable and I can iterate on to that variable to access the properties and methods of each child ?

Any help is appreciated !!!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean children which are the same components, not  and  in example, and you really have multiple component instances like:

```
<some-container>
  <app-child></app-child>
  <app-child></app-child>
  <app-child></app-child>
</some-container>
```

Then you can get all of them by @ViewChildren decorator as I provided below:

```
@ViewChildren(AppChildComponent) public QueryList<AppChildComponent>;
```

And you can iteratee them with 'forEach' method which are exists in QueryList.

Comment: You are repeating the same child <app-child></app-child>. In my case all child's are different one. (child1, child2 .. and so on )